# React onClick not firing on first click, second click behaves as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want the SVG picture to change when I press the button onclick() . But it only work on second press.

```
    const [taskList, setTaskList] = useState([]);
    const [indexTask, setIndexTask]=useState({});
    const [statusTask, setStatusTask]=useState(false);


const markComplete = (props)=>{
        let tempList = taskList;
        for(let i=0; i<tempList.length; i++){
            if(indexTask===i){
                tempList[i].status = props;
            }     
        }
        setTaskList([...tempList]);
    }
```

```
 {taskList.map((obj,i)=>   
                    <div key={i} className='div-task'>
                        <div className='div-task-container'>
                            <div className='div-task-status'>
                                <div className='div-task-status-complete' onClick={()=>{markComplete(true); setIndexTask(i)}} role={'button'}>
                                <SvgTaskUncomplete statusTask={obj.status} setStatusTask={setStatusTask} ></SvgTaskUncomplete>
                                </div>
                                <div className='div-task-status-uncomplete' onClick={()=>{markComplete(false); setIndexTask(i)}} role={'button'}>
                                <SvgTaskComplete statusTask={obj.status} setStatusTask={setStatusTask}></SvgTaskComplete>
                                </div>
```

I want the SVG picture to change when I press the button onclick(). But it only work on second press.
[first click on button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoe0j.png)
[second click on button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kCHq.png)

Comment: `let tempList = taskList;` - this does nothing, you've just created another variable referencing the same object

Comment: I know, I just took the finished structure as an example and it worked

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the posted code might be over complicating with the `indexTask` state.

Try this version that passes the `index` to `markComplete` directly:

```
const [taskList, setTaskList] = useState([]);
const [statusTask, setStatusTask]=useState(false);

const markComplete = (status, index) => {
  const tempList = [...taskList];
  tempList[index].status = status;
  setTaskList(tempList);
};
```

```
{taskList.map((obj,i)=>   
  <div key={i} className='div-task'>
      <div className='div-task-container'>
          <div className='div-task-status'>
              <div className='div-task-status-complete' onClick={()=>{markComplete(true, i)}} role={'button'}>
              <SvgTaskUncomplete statusTask={obj.status} setStatusTask={setStatusTask} ></SvgTaskUncomplete>
              </div>
              <div className='div-task-status-uncomplete' onClick={()=>{markComplete(false, i)}} role={'button'}>
              <SvgTaskComplete statusTask={obj.status} setStatusTask={setStatusTask}></SvgTaskComplete>
              </div>
```

The posted code is partial so could not test it, but hopefully this could still help as a reference.